# How to write this Linq to NHibernate query

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

We have an entity like this :

```
public class File{
       public int Region{get;set;}
       public bool ShowLocation{get;set;}
       //Other fields are omitted
}
```

I would like to write this query:

```
    SELECT Region,SUM(CASE WHEN ShowLocation=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS
 ShowCount,SUM(CASE WHEN ShowLocation=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NotShowCount
--WHERE omitted for the sake of simplicity
GROUP BY Region
```

For some reasons I would like to use Linq To Nhibernate (We have a complex filtering mechanism that generates an `Expression<Func<File,bool>>`)

So far I couldn't find any way to achieve this using Linq To NHibernate.
Here's some of my attempts:

Conditioanl Count:(No exception but it count all rows anyway)

```
    Files
    .Where(whereExpression)
    .GroupBy(x=>x.Region)
    .Select(x=>new
    {
        x.Region,
        ShowCount=x.Count(f=>f.ShowLocation==1),
        NotShowCount=x.Count(f=>f.ShowLocation==0)
    });
```

Conditioanl Sum : Not Supported/Implemented Exception

```
Files
.Where(whereExpression)
.GroupBy(x=>x.Region)
.Select(x=>new 
{
  x.Region,
  ShowCount=x.SUM(f=>f.ShowLocation==1?1:0),
  NotShowCount=x.SUM(f=>f.ShowLocation==0?1:0)
});
```

SELECT Before GROUP : Not Supported/Implemented Exception

```
    Files.Where(whereExpression).Select(x=>new
    {
       x.Region,
       Show=x.ShowLocation==1?1:0,
       NotShow=x.ShowLocation==0?1:0
    })
    .GroupBy(x=>x.Region)
    .Select(x=>new 
    {
       x.Region,
       ShowCount=x.SUM(f=>f.Show),
       NotShowCount=x.SUM(f=>f.NotShow)
    });
```

UNION : Not Supported/Implemented Exception

```
    Files
       .Where(whereExpression)
       .Where(x=>x.ShowLocation==1)
 .Select(x=>new
{
x.Region,
Show=1,NotShow=0
})
.Union(Files
 .Where(whereExpression)
.Where(x=>x.ShowLocation==0)
.Select(x=>new
{x.Region,
Show=0,
NotShow=1
}))
.GroupBy(x=>x.Region)
.Select(x=>new 
{
x.Region,
CountShow=x.Count(a=>a.Show),
CountNotShow=x.Count(a=>a.NotShow)
});
```

I have no other clues. Any other idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can get that to work with Linq to NH. Would you be able to use QueryOver instead? The QueryOver API also takes an `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` in the where clause so you should be able to get it to work like this with your existing filter:

```
            MyDto dto = null;

            var myDtoList = session.QueryOver<File>()
                .Select(
                    Projections.Group<File>(x => x.Region).WithAlias(() => dto.Region),
                    Projections.Sum(
                        Projections.Conditional(
                            Restrictions.Where<File>(c => c.ShowLocation== 1),
                            Projections.Constant(1),
                            Projections.Constant(0))).WithAlias(() => dto.ShowCount),
                    Projections.Sum(
                        Projections.Conditional(
                            Restrictions.Where<File>(c => c.ShowLocation== 0),
                            Projections.Constant(1),
                            Projections.Constant(0))).WithAlias(() => dto.NotShowCount))
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<MyDto>())
                .List<MyDto>();
```

QueryOver doesn't really work with anonymous types so you will have to define `MyDto` with the properties you want to return, ie `Region`, `ShowCount` and `NotShowCount`

Comment: Unfortunately as I mentioned in my question I am afraid that I have to use Linq to NHibernate.

Comment: @Beatles1692 OK sorry about that, I thought you only wanted to use Linq to Nh because you want to reuse your filtering mechanism that returns `Expression<Func<File,bool>>`

Comment: The problem is `QueryOver` doesn't support some of `Linq expressions` such as `Any`

Comment: There is some way of creating your own extension methods for nhibernate linq provider. Have a look at this maybe: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318177/Creating-In-and-NotIn-extension-methods-for-NHiber and maybe try to create your own extension, ie SumWhere(x=>x.ShowLocation==1) or something like that. I've never tried it but it might be worth a shot?

Answer (score 1):

I used your second attempt and inserted a `ToList()` before the `Select()`. The result would look like that:

```
Files
.Where(whereExpression)
.GroupBy(x=>x.Region)
.ToList<IGrouping<int, File>>()
.Select(x=>new 
{
  x.Key,
  ShowCount = x.Sum(f => f.ShowLocation == 1 ? 1 : 0),
  NotShowCount = x.Sum(f => f.ShowLocation == 0 ? 1 : 0)
});
```

In this way the Select is applied to a List instead of the IQueryable.

Comment: Well that could be an alternative if I can't find a way to create my query in any other way :) thanks

Comment: Okay I tested it and it turned out a very bad idea because it doesn't allow you to project the only columns that you need before GroupBy and thus it would try to fetch all the object graph whether they are not lazy loaded and in our case it results to a SELECT N+1 :)